# "The SQL statement is not valid. There are no columns detected in the statement"

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot

I am merging data from one file that contains six different sheets or tabs. All sheets contain the same headers. For the task I am using PowerPivot.

1st I created a connection using Excel and selected the file/imported Sheet1
2nd I activated my PowerPivot > Design > Existing Connections
3rd Table properties Table Name [Sheet1] > Switch to [Query Editor]

Here's my SQL that resulted the error in the title:

```
  Select [Sheet1$].* From [Sheet1$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet2$].* FROM `C:\_TEST\HG.xlsx`.[Shee2$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet3$].* FROM `C:\_TEST\HG.xlsx`.[Shee3$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet4$].* FROM `C:\_TEST\HG.xlsx`.[Shee4$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet5$].* FROM `C:\_TEST\HG.xlsx`.[Shee5$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet6$].* FROM `C:\_TEST\HG.xlsx`.[Shee6$]
```

When I validated the statement had the error:

> The SQL statement is not valid. There are no columns detected in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

To answer and share how I resolved my question I found that when I created the connection I can still select sheets 2 to 6 in the dropdown from existing connections. So I tried this code .........and resolved the error :).

```
 Select [Sheet1$].* From [Sheet1$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet2$].* FROM [Shee2$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet3$].* FROM [Shee3$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet4$].* FROM [Shee4$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet5$].* FROM [Shee5$]
  UNION ALL
  Select [Sheet6$].* FROM [Shee6$]
```